# Docker EACCES permission denied mkdir

Tags: docker, docker-compose, chown

My friend gave me a project with a dockerfile which seems to work just fine for him but I get a permission error.

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/node-app && chown -R node:node /usr/src/node-app

WORKDIR /usr/src/node-app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
COPY ./api/package.json ./api/
COPY ./iso/package.json  ./iso/

USER node
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000
```

> `error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/node-app/node_modules/<project_name>/api/node_modules'".`

Could it be a docker version error?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that when you run the container, you map a host directory to /usr/src or /usr/src/node-app in the container. The `node` user in the container has UID 1000 and GID 1000. You need to make sure that a user with those ids can write to the directory on your host. Your friend has done that and that's why it works for him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`COPY` normally copies things into the image owned by root, and it will create directories inside the image if they don't exist.  In particular, when you `COPY ./api/package.json ./api/`, it creates the `api` subdirectory owned by root, and when you later try to run `yarn install`, it can't create the `node_modules` subdirectory because you've switched users.

I'd recommend copying files into the container and running the build process as root.  Don't `chown` anything; leave all of these files owned by root.  Switch to an alternate `USER` only at the very end of the Dockerfile, where you declare the `CMD`.  This means that the non-root user running the container won't be able to modify the code or libraries in the container, intentionally or otherwise, which is a generally good security practice.

```sh
FROM node:alpine

# Don't RUN mkdir; WORKDIR creates the directory if it doesn't exist

WORKDIR /usr/src/node-app

# All of these files and directories are owned by root
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
COPY ./api/package.json ./api/
COPY ./iso/package.json  ./iso/
# Run this installation command still as root
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

# Copy in the rest of the application, still as root
COPY . .
# RUN yarn build

# Declare how to run the container -- _now_ switch to a non-root user
EXPOSE 3000
USER node
CMD yarn start
```

Comment: Is not it dangerous to do `npm ci` and `npm run build` as root for our container? what if one of our 3rd party packages be a malware (Disclaimer: I am not sure if this is even possible)?